# Php pagination from Mysql Select * Where; If click on next page number, then displays all rows from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

In input field user enters condition - what data to get from mysql. For example, user wants to get mysql rows where month is October (or 10).

Here I get user input `$date_month = $_POST['date_month'];`

Then mysql statement and code for pagination

```
try {
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE RecordMonth = ? ");
$sql->execute(array($date_month));

foreach ($sql as $i => $row) {
}

$number_of_fetched_rows = $i;
$number_of_results_per_page = 100;
$total_pages = ceil($number_of_fetched_rows / $number_of_results_per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
$show_page = $_GET['page'];

if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
$start = ($show_page -1) * $number_of_results_per_page;
$end = $start + $number_of_results_per_page; 
}
else {

$start = 0;
$end = $number_of_results_per_page; 
}   
}
else {
$start = 0;
$end = $number_of_results_per_page; 
}

for ($page_i = 1; $page_i <= $total_pages; $page_i++) {
echo "<a href='__filter_mysql_data.php?page=$page_i'>| $page_i |</a> ";
}

}
```

So, user enters month (10), script displays all rows where month is 10; displays page No 1. But if user click on other page number, script displays all data from mysql (all months, not only 10)

What I see - when click on other page number, page reloads, that means that values of php variables "dissapears". As understand after page reload `$date_month` value is not set (has lost/"dissapears") ? How to keep the value? Or may be some better solution for pagination?

Update.

Behavior is following:

1) in input field set month 10 (October);

2) click on button and get displayed data from mysql where month is 10 (October); so far is ok

3) click on page number 2 and get displayed **all** data from mysql (**all months, not only 10 (October)**)

Tried to use `LIMIT` however it does not help.

Possibly problem is related with this code

```
for ($page_i = 1; $page_i <= $total_pages; $page_i++) {
echo "<a href='__filter_mysql_data.php?page=$page_i'>| $page_i |</a> ";
}
```

When click on `$page_i` for not understandable (for me) reasons get displayed all (not filtered) data from mysql. If I use `LIMIT` also get displayed **not filtered** results from mysql....

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` in your query, have a look at the following [example](http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=1) , you can try something like :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    2_1_journal 
WHERE 
    RecordMonth = ? 
LIMIT [start_row],[number_of_rows_per_page]
```

So for example lets say you have 2 pages with 10 rows per page then the `LIMIT` for the 2 queries (one per page) will be:

1) `LIMIT 0,10`
2) `LIMIT 10,10`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE RecordMonth = ? LIMIT = $number_of_results_per_page OFFSET ($page_number*$number_of_results_per_page);
```

Here you need to calculate the page number also and you should use the limit and offset concept of mysql.